# SQL restore database from .bak to a different machine - Errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to restore a database from a backup I got on the hosting server. 
I have checked the logical names using:

```
restore FILELISTONLY from 
disk = 'c:\DBBackup2_17092013.bak'
```

and used them to perform the following query:

```
restore database StadlerTest
from disk = 'c:\DBBackup2_17092013.bak'
with replace,
move 'Stadler_base' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\StadlerTest.mdf',
move 'Stadler_base_log' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\StadlerTest.ldf'
```

I run the above two queries from master after I created the empty database StadlerTest but I  am getting a series of error that sound like these (translation from italian):

*""Message 3634, level 16, state 1, row 1
The operating system returned error '5(Access denied.)' during the attempt to 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\StadlerTest.mdf'.""*

I am doing something wrong but I do not know what is wrong, I already checked  several answers given on SO and other sites but I am not getting it right. Some help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a permissions error.  SQL Server may not have permissions to create files there.   Remember, SQL Server is trying to create the database under its service account, not your windows login.  Check the permissions of the SQL Server account, found with all other logins under Security -> Logins in management studio.

However, you should not create databases on the C drive.   If they grow and the C drive runs out of space your whole computer and operating system will tank.  If at all possible, put the database files on a different drive.  If this is just for personal testing use, that is fine but not for any important system.

Comment: Well...the bak is on c because I was lazy to put it somewhere else and write the path. But the destination db is in the sql server directory. Actually i need to recover only the tables to modify the asp pages. Thanks but, I am the admin of the machine logged as admin I should not have permission problems. I think?

Comment: @FeliceM Yes, but it isn't YOU creating the database, it is SQL Server.  It doesn't matter how many permissions you have, only how much permissions the SQL Server has.  Give the SQL Server account the permissions it needs to access that path.  The SQL Server account to use is determined when you install the Server and will be listed with all other logins inside of the Security -> Logins tab of management studios.

Comment: Thats quite interesting thank you. I will test in a few hours and let you know. Thanks for now. Good hint.

Comment: Hi, I moved the .bak in the same directory of the destination but looks like I get the same problem. I do not think the problem is about  credentials on the disk but maybe it is about the .bak which could be password protected since it is coming from the hosting server were the db has a password. I am not coming right. However thanks for the support.